DMA - need clarity
We have an old SQL Server 2008 R2 and we are trying to migrate to the latest SQL Server version. My product owner is asking me to check the compatibility of stored procedures  with the new version.
Does the DMA (Data Migration Assistant) cover stored procedures or is there an alternative process?
